# Dynamic columns with List<List> in <p:dataTable><p:columns>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dynamic-columns

I'm attempting  to generate a `dataTable` with columns dinamycally, so I've a `List<List>`
when a `List` inside of a `List` is the content of my column, but when I try to show it I can't display not much.

So, this is the code of my Bean:

```java
@ManagedBean
@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped
public class Controlador {

   private List<List> estadistico;

   @PostConstruct
   public void inicializar(){
      this.estadistico = new ArrayList<List>();

      this.estadistico.add(  Arrays.asList( new Integer[]{0,1,24})); 
      this.estadistico.add(  Arrays.asList( new Integer[]{5,1,34})); 
      this.estadistico.add(  Arrays.asList( new Integer[]{12,1,4})); 

   }
   //getter's and setter's
}
```

And this is the view:

```xhtml
<h:form>
    <!-- estadistico is  List<List> -->
    <p:dataTable value="#{controlador.estadistico}" var="lista">
        <!-- lista is List of numbers
             and I suppose that value is each number
         -->
        <p:columns value="#{lista}" var="value" >
               #{value}
        </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I expected some like :

```
---------------
0     5    12 
---------------
1     1    1
---------------
24    34   4
---------------
```

what am I doing wrong?

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<p:columns value>` cannot refer the `<p:dataTable var>`. It is technically and logically not possible to control the columns on a per-row basis. They have to be controlled on a per-table basis.

If your model guarantees that every nested list has the same size, then this should do:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{controlador.estadistico}" var="lista">
    <p:columns value="#{controlador.estadistico[0]}" columnIndexVar="i">
        #{lista[i]}
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

See also the [`<p:columns>` showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml).

Comment: Thanks for you answer faster, but I get values like a row, row 1: `0 1 24` row 2: `5 1 34` and row 3: `12 1 4`

Comment: Right, just fix the model accordingly so that it returns exactly what the view expects.