# c:forEach or ui:repeat inside h:dataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a `h:dataTable` retrieving a list of objects.  For each of those objects I have to display some object information (`obj.x`, `obj.y`) but also a list of children linked to that `obj`.

I coded a function to retrieve the children.  This function looks like this :

```
public List<ChildModel> getChildren(ObjectModel obj) {
    List<ChildModel> children = //...
    return children;
}
```

Since a want to display the children on a single line I thought about using a loop :

```
<h:dataTable value="objectList" var="obj">
  ...
  <c:forEach items="#{someBean.getChildren(obj)" var="child" >
     ...
  </c:forEach>
</h:dataTable>
```

But I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.  When switching to a `h:dataTable` (like this) everything works fine :

```
<h:dataTable value="objectList" var="obj">
  ...
  <h:dataTable value="#{someBean.getChildren(obj)" var="child" >
     ...
  </h:dataTable>
</h:dataTable>
```

I also tried with a `ui:repeat` but I think (maybe wrongly) that it is not possible.

What I am missing?

Comment: The `ui:repeat` is correct one there since variable in `h:dataTable` is accessible only in render view time (it is the time where `ui:repeat` takes place so it works) in contrary to `c:forEach` which takes place in view build time. During view build time variable from render view time (your `h:dataTable` `var`) does not yet exist hence null. To learn more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021036/why-can-cforeach-or-uirepeat-not-access-pdatatable-var

Comment: @Geinmachi `ui:repeat` also gives me `java.lang.NullPointerException`.  In the link you provided it looks like `c:forEach` will work only if it adds `p:column`.

Comment: @balusC I don't want to dynamically add columns.  If I understand well the answer you provided, I have to replace the outer `h:dataTable` by a `ui:repeat` and do the "table presentation stuff" all by myself?

Comment: Just replace `<c:forEach>` by `<ui:repeat>`. Their lifecycles are explained in the dupe and particularly the link therein http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Comment: @balusC It now works with `ui:repeat` but I had to do something weird : in `getChildren(ObjectModel obj)` I have to check if the `obj` parameter is `null` and, if so, I need to return an empty `List<ChildModel>` array.  It looks like the `h:dataTable` iterates on all the obj of the  `objectList` **plus** one last time with a `null` value.

Comment: Business logic in getter methods is bad idea anyway. Better prepare exactly the model the view expects. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times