# Display List<List> in <p:dataTable><p:columns>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am trying to display below list of list of object in datatable. But nothing is showing up. Help is very much appreciated!

```
public class TimrsDisplayBean {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String teamName = "";
    private String teamType = "";
    private boolean reported;
    private boolean noProd;
    private boolean missing;

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public String getTeamType() {
        return teamType;
    }

    public void setTeamType(String teamType) {
        this.teamType = teamType;
    }
    public boolean getReported() {
        return reported;
    }
    public void setReported(boolean reported) {
        this.reported = reported;
    }

    public boolean getNoProd() {
        return noProd;
    }

    public void setNoProd(boolean noProd) {
        this.noProd = noProd;
    }

    public boolean getMissing() {
        return missing;
    }

    public void setMissing(boolean missing) {
        this.missing = missing;
    }
}
```

XHTML FILE

```
<p:dataTable value="#{dashboardMBean.timrsDisplayDataList}" var="var" rowIndexVar="row"
                                styleClass="large-card-datatable alternatingRowTable no-border nowrap">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <span class="updateDate"> </span>
                                </f:facet>
                                <p:column headerText="Type" value=" #{dashboardMBean.timrsDisplayDataList[0]}" columnIndexVar="i">   
                                    #{var[i].teamType}
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Type" value=" #{dashboardMBean.timrsDisplayDataList[0]}" columnIndexVar="i">   
                                    #{var[i].teamName}
                                </p:column>
```

Comment: List<List<TimrsDisplayBean>> timrsDisplayDataList = new ArrayList<List<TimrsDisplayBean>>(); is list I am trying to display

Comment: What is `columnIndexVar`? I don't think that attribute exists for a `p:column`.

Comment: I am not using rowIndexVar. I can remove it was just trying diff things.

Comment: Same goes for `value`. See what happens if you simply put `<p:column headerText="Type">#{var}</p:column>`. That should give you the `toString()` of whatever is in `var`. If not, please post the relevant parts of your `dashboardMBean`.

Comment: #{var} display the list of objects but not the value of teamType in the object. If I use #{var[0].teamType} it shows the teamType of first object in the list but not the rest of objects in the list.

Comment: In that case, what exactly is your problem? Are you looking for JSTL forEach? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148658/iterate-over-elements-of-list-and-map-using-jstl-cforeach-tag

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007189/dynamic-columns-with-listlist-in-pdatatablepcolumns?

Comment: @Kukeltje Interesting. NetBeans does not offer those attributes. I'm not sure if this is a duplicate.. Not even sure what the problem is. Looks like simply using a single list is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Please support full code parts if possible. Your `datatable` tag doesn't even finish.

Beside that, it seems like you've done too much work. Did you try to calculate the row indices by yourself? Not needed. The basic column definiton is more comfortable. Use your defined variable `var` to name each element/row as shown in the Primefaces showcase:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml

In your case, it will be something like

```
<p:column headerText="Type">
    <h:outputText value="#{var.teamType}"/>
</p:column>
```

Plus, as Jasper De Vries said correctly, there is no attribute called `columnIndexVar`. Remove it to prevent strange behaviour.

If this is not enough, you need to share some more code of your ManagedBean. Not sure if your posted java class represent your Bean, but if so, you need to declare it as a ManagedBean like

```
@ManagedBean(name = "timrsDisplayBean)
@SessionScoped
public class TimrsDisplayBean {
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Are you implying to use a single (non nested) list?

Comment: I personally would recommend a solution like this. I am not a fan of (multiple..!) nested data structures. If you have to insist on a nested list, I would suggest to use something like a `RowExpansion` to show the details respectively the nested list objects. But, honestly, I miss several information/source codes in this question, e.g. the setter/getter of `timrsDisplayDataList`